# Equivalent Definition of Solvable Groups in Serre’s Book

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, solvable-groups, group-extensions

In Serre's Linear Representations of Finite Groups, Section 8.2, the following claim is given, as equivalent to a definition of solvable groups.

> Solvable groups. One says that G is solvable if there exists a sequence
> $$\{1\}=G_0\subset G_1\subset\cdots\subset G_n=G$$
> of subgroups of $G$, with $G_{i-1}$ normal in $G_i$ and $G_i/G_{i-1}$ abelian for $1\le i\le n$.
>
> > Equivalent definition: $G$ is obtained from the group $\{1\}$ by a finite number of extensions with abelian kernels.

In the same section, the following claim is given, as equivalent to a definition of nilpotent groups to show that finite nilpotent $\Rightarrow$supersolvable.

> Nilpotent groups. As Same above, except that one requires that all the $G_i$ be normal in G and $G_i/G_{i-1}$ be in the center of $G/G_i$ for $1\le i\le n$.
>
> > Equivalent definition: $G$ is obtained from the group $\{1\}$ by a finite number of central extensions.

I showed the equivalence of the definition of nilpotent groups and
the equivalent definition$\Rightarrow$ solvable. However, the converse could not be shown...

Therefore, is it equivalent to an equivalence definition in the case of solvable groups? I would like to know if there are any counterexamples.

Comment: As nilpotent groups, the equivalent definition ⇒ solvable could be shown. However, the sequence of subgroups obtained is normal in G. My question is solvable⇒the equivalent definition.

Comment: A sufficient condition for solvability is the existence of a subnormal series with abelian quotients, so you only need the sequence of subgroups to be subnormal in the whole group. To see that, just note that if there is a finite subnormal series with abelian quotients implies that the derived series is finite and ends at the trivial subgroup.

Comment: What is your definition of "solvable" group? There are, after all, many equivalent ways of defining it...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added the definition of solvable group.

Comment: Are you familiar with the commutator subgroup and the derived series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the definition of the commutator subgroup and derived series:

If $x,y\in G$, then $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$. If $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $G$, then $[A,B]=\langle [a,b]\mid a\in A, b\in B\rangle$.

The commutator sugbroup of $G$ is $[G,G]$. This is a normal (in fact, characteristic) subgroup of $G$, and for any subgroup $N$ of $G$, $[G,G]\leq N$ if and only if $n\triangleleft G$ and $G/N$ is abelian.

The derived series of $G$ is defined inductively by $G^{(1)}=[G,G]$ and $G^{(k+1)}=[G^{(k)},G^{(k)}]$. They are all normal subgroups.

Assume that $G$ has a subnormal series
$$1=G_0\lt G_1\lt\cdots \lt G_n=G$$
with $G_i\triangleleft G_{i+1}$ and $G_{i+1}/G_i$ abelian.

**Claim.** $G^{(i)}\leq G_{m-i}$.

We proceed inductively: Since $G/G_{m-1}$ is abelian, then $G^{(1)}\leq G_{m-1}$.

Now assume that $G^{(k)}\leq G_{m-k}$. Since $G_{m-k}/G_{m-k-1}$ is abelian, then $[G_{m-k},G_{m-k}]\leq G_{m-k-q}$. Since $G^{(k)}\leq G_{m-k}$, we have
$$ G^{(k+1)} = [G^{(k)},G^{(k)}] \leq [G_{m-k},G_{m-k}]\leq G_{m-k-1}$$
we have $G^{(k+1)}\leq G_{m-(k+1)}$, as claimed.

That means that $G^{(m)}=1$. Now consider the normal series
$$1 = G^{(m)}\leq G^{(m+1)} \leq\cdots\leq G^{(1)} \leq G$$
which exhibits $G$ as a series of extensions with abelian kernel starting from $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it is true that solvable⇔derived series is finite. “extension with Abelian kernel” is an extension of groups with commutative kernel dividing G (central extension is a kind of group extension), but is that not true? I would appreciate it if you could tell me what you mean by extension with Abelian kernel.

Comment: @Daichi A group is solvable if the and only if the derived series terminates in the identity after finitely many steps. I understand "$G$ is obtained from $\{1\}$ by a finite number of extensions with abelian kernels" to mean that $G$ has an abelian normal subgroup $N_1$, and $G/N_1$ has an abelian normal subgroup $N_2/N_1$, and $G/N_2$ has an abelian normal subgroup $N_3/N_2$, and so on, and after finitely many steps you reach and abelian normal subgroup $N_m/N_{m-1}$ with $G/N_m$ abelian. Why do you think I meant something else?

Comment: Thank you for your very thorough reply. My question was about the part $[G,G]\le N\Leftrightarrow N$ is normal in $G$ and $G/N$ is abelian, I understand that if N is normal, the equivalence holds, but I did not understand $[G,G]\le N\Rightarrow N$ is normal in $G$. Sorry for asking a simple question.

Comment: @Daichi Since $G/[G,G]$ is abelian, every subgroup is normal. So $N/[G,G]\triangleleft G/[G,G]$, so $N\triangleleft G$. Alternatively, if $g\in G$ and $n\in N$, then $[g,n^{-1}]=g^{-1}ngn^{-1}\in [G,G]\leq N$, so $g^{-1}ng = [g,n^{-1}]n\in N$.

Comment: @Aruturo Magidin Thank you for your reply. I did not know until now that the derived series are normal in G! It is also interesting to note that there is no need for N normality. Thanks to you.